# How to use a variable in an IF EXIST clause in batch scripts

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Is there a way to get the value of a variable in an if exist command in batch scripts?

for example

```
@echo off 
set fi=ab.txt

FOR /L %%i IN (0 1 2) DO (
    set fi=a.txt
    if exist %fi% (
        echo do something
    )
)
```

Comment: A variable is displayed like this `%variablename%`, not like this `%%variablename`, and your `For /L` loop is incorrectlly wirtten. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, then do the same with `set /?`.

Comment: The code corrections look good and it should work now but, I don't see the point of your code.  Your code will execute in less than a half second.  What is the point of check for a file three times that quickly?

Comment: yes, the previous code worked. But I want to update the fi variable during the for loop, the if condition fails

Comment: If that's the case, you'll need to enable delayed expansion, _(using `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion`)_, and expand your variable like this, `!variablename!`.

Answer (score 0):

In the current state your code is in, you require `delayedexpansion`.

You however do not need to create the code block with the `set` as you have and can therefore eliminate `delayedexpansion`. The reason I say it is not needed is because of the unknown reason for `set fi=ab.txt` and then `set`ting it to something else in the loop. Therefore it is the same as this:

```
@echo off 
set fi=ab.txt rem What is the purpose when you re`set` it right after?
set fi=a.txt

For /L %%i IN (0,1,2) DO (
    if exist %fi% (
        echo do something
    )
)
```

If however your intension is to set a variable based on the `for` loop metavariable values, then you would need `delayedexpansion`. This example demonstrates the usage of the metavariables in the `set` as well as transforming from `%var%` to `delayedexpansion`'s `!var!`.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set fi=ab.txt

FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,2) DO (
    set "fi=a%%i.txt"
    if exist !fi! (
        echo do something
    )
)
```

Final thought, if it is however like the first example, I am unsure as to why you want to check for something multiple times in a loop, unless you are expecting a file to land within milliseconds.